# How to Add Items to List of Lists C#

Tags: c#

I am writing file processing system where I need groups of files to stay together.  I figured I need a list of strings and a list of (list of strings) but I am not able add anything to my lists.   Visual Studio isn't offering me .Add for my lists.

```
    usings ....

    namespace Main
    {

    public class SisterFiles : List<string>
    { }

    public class FileGroups : List<SisterFiles>
    { }

    static class Program
    { 

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>

        [STAThread]

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // here is where I would like to assign a list of files to instances of SisterFiles
           // here is where I'd like to add each SisterFile list to FileGroups
           //  but VS only offers Equals/Enumerate or Reference Equals
```

---->>>> Wouldn't let me add anything             SisterFiles { ""} //

```
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //  go through the list and make sure all the files are together
            //  if they are together
            //   run the program


        }
    }
}
```

Any advice would be helpful.  I know I have a lot to learn about classes and lists!

Comment: the given code is not relevant for the question. Please show what you have tried or what is the code that is failing

Comment: One would generally create classes that *contain* a `List`, not classes that *are* a list.

Comment: What part do you need help with? Is there something specific that you don't understand?

Comment: guys it's one line do you really need someone to show the code `fileGroups[index].Add(MyValue)` assuming you've declared a variable fileGroups

Comment: I suggest you to read the [official `List` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and maybe take a C# tutorial to get used to the syntax and programming language (but don't ask for a tutorial here, it's off-topic!)

Comment: @GiladGreen I tried right after my comments to add items to the list but not successfully.

Comment: I suggest that you **declare variables** rather than create new classes.

Comment: @johnny5 `FileGroups` is a class, so your suggested solution will not compile.

Comment: @Missy: What did you try and how did it fail?  You need to explain what's wrong in order for anybody to help.  Provide a complete example which demonstrates the problem.  Things like `usings ...` are vague and unhelpful.

Comment: Basic C# Tutorials. Understand them. You do not create classes for everything - you use existing classes and Composite them together to build things that are.  For starters I would recommend to view the documentation alongside `Directory`, `File`, `FileInfo`and `DirectoryInfo` which should enable you to query your local filesystem and gather informations about files present. You find these classen in the [`System.IO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace (<-- Link to it)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yeah I was pseudo coding it because I assumed they would figure it out since there is no declared variable

Comment: @johnny5 A beginner is not going to magically "figure it out" from incorrect code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yeah I was gonna say that, people can learn things but I guess you can't fix Lazy.

Comment: Freaking so many haters.  Yeah -- I can't figure it out.  I don't need the down votes.  Can someone help me?   I will uptick you and pick your answer.  Just show me how to do it right.

Comment: @Missy I've posed a comment on how to do it.  Declare a variable, and find your index and just call Add what is so difficult?

Comment: @Missy: Please focus less on the votes or your emotional responses and more on the problem you are trying to solve.  What *actual code* did you write and what *actual error* did you see?  "It won't let me" doesn't describe the problem.  Write a line of code which attempts to do what you want.  Does that line produce an error?  What was the code?  What was the error?

Comment: I think my constructors aren't right.  FileGroups.Add(SisterFiles("CRMD", ""); does not work and FileGroups.Add(("CRMD", "")); still don't work.

Comment: @Missy: Those aren't constructors.  And you're trying to call instance methods statically.  And "still don't work" isn't an error message.  The syntax you're attempting to use *strongly* suggests that what you're looking for is introductory tutorials on C#.  If you write a line of code that doesn't do what you expect, explain what you expected and *why* you expected it.  Randomly typing things that look like code is not programming.

Comment: @Missy Most of us are here to help. From what I see, you are missing some very fundamental concepts that are explained well in many places. We are not in the practice of repeating material which you can find with a quick google search. I suggest that you find a good C# tutorial or textbook that explains the important concepts of classes and how to create variables from them. You will do yourself a huge favor by putting some effort to read and learn from existing material rather than have every detail spoon fed to you.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - I have read many books and I am still confused on certain things like static classes and enumerators and things like this.  I don't expect to have everything automagically work out.

Comment: @David  -- still don't work == VS won't offer me any options that will allow me to add to the list.

Comment: Okay - I needed to declare instance variable in order to add to it.   Seriously -- 10 people not helping and one poor sod gets downvoted for giving it a go?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can correct your structure as follows.

```
public class SisterFiles 
{
    public List<string> lstString;
}

public class FileGroups
{
    public List<SisterFiles> lstSisterFiles;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SisterFiles sisterFiles = new SisterFiles();
        sisterFiles.lstString.Add("My String");

        FileGroups fileGroup = new FileGroups();
        fileGroup.lstSisterFiles = new List<SisterFiles>();
        fileGroup.lstSisterFiles.Add(sisterFiles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I will try it.

Comment: Thanks  -- that gave me the boost I needed to solve the problem.