# how do you add members to a List

Tags: c#, list

I have a file with 14 lines of information about each of 100 members. I want to create a List where each member of the List contains the 14 lines.

I created a Class for each of the lines in the file. But when I run the code none of the information in the lines of the file get added to the List. During debug "data" remains zero.

```
    private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        int itemcount = 0;int membercount = 0;
        string[] roundData = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\sirslist\\data.txt");
      List<Member[]> data = new List<Member[]>();
      string[] item = new string[roundData.Length];
      while (membercount < roundData.Length / 14)
       {
        for (int i = itemcount; i < itemcount + 14; i++)
        {
            item[i] = roundData[i];
        }
        new Member()
        {
            BadgeNo = item[itemcount],
            LastName = item[itemcount + 1],
            MiddleInitial = item[itemcount + 2],
            FirstName = item[itemcount + 3],
            Nickname = item[itemcount + 4],
            WifeName = item[itemcount + 5],
            Address = item[itemcount + 6],
            ZipCode = item[itemcount + 7],
            Phone = item[itemcount + 8],
            Email = item[itemcount + 9],
            WeddingMonth = item[itemcount + 10],
            BirthDate = item[itemcount + 11],
            Employment = item[itemcount + 12],
            Interests = item[itemcount + 13],
        };
        data.ToList();
        membercount++;
        itemcount += 14;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Please specify the language you are using in the tags

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Add Items to List of Lists C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677154/how-to-add-items-to-list-of-lists-c-sharp) AND/OR https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+item+to+list

Comment: There is ample [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add) of the various methods of `List<T>`...

Comment: Additionally there are 141,200 posts here bearing the `list` tag, many are going to illustrate how to add; there is no additional charge to view them

Answer (score -1):

First, your `data` list should be declared like this:

```
List<Member> data = new List<Member>();
```

Second, your are not adding the members to the list:

```
var member = new Member() { ... }
data.Add(member);
```